# Unable to retrieve public metrics using tweepy.Client

Tags: python, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I don't know what the deal is, but I'm trying to get user info by usernames and include their public_metrics from the Twitter API using [tweepy](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.get_users).

Here's my code:

```
import tweepy
BEARER_TOKEN = 'a 100% real API secret publicly posted on SO'
tweepyClient = tweepy.Client(BEARER_TOKEN)
response = tweepyClient.get_users(usernames=['ThreatLevelGG', 'Twitter', 'TwitterDev'], user_fields=['public_metrics'])
```

However, it's only returning the default info:
[image]

Am I stupidly missing something simple, or does tweepy suck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [relevant FAQ section in Tweepy's documentation about this](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.6.0/faq.html#why-am-i-not-getting-expansions-or-fields-data-with-api-v2-using-client):

> If you are simply printing the objects and looking at that output, the string representations of API v2 models/objects only include the default attributes that are guaranteed to exist.
>
> The objects themselves still include the relevant data, which you can access as attributes or by key, like a dictionary.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question. Have tried to access it as if its a dict but not getting anywhere but it could be I'm not doing the dict access currently. Could not tell from this answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to when you say "it", but instances of `User` and other Twitter API models/objects are exactly that, instances of specific classes, not dictionaries.

Comment: This works, my confusion was that I was looking at get_users_mentions instead of get_users_tweets. Hope this helps someone.